# How can I package a Kivy IOS app while on linux?

Tags: python, ios, linux, kivy

I have created a .py and .kv file for my game, now I must package it. I, however, do not own a mac. I have a linux and a windows computer, I prefer linux. Is it possible for me to make an Iphone app without using a Mac?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041623/develop-iphone-app-without-a-mac http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276907/starting-iphone-app-development-in-linux

Answer (score 3):

I think it's technically possible (though against apple's TOS) to use a virtual machine, though there are many problems you can encounter in setting this up.

It may also be possible to use some online provider, but I don't think I've seen an example of this with kivy in particular.

There's no way to do it natively on linux, due to apple's toolchain requirements.